# How is OAuth 2.0 "Implicit Flow" better than "Resource Owner Password"?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am just getting started with IdentityServer4 and working my way through different tutorials and articles.

I understand that there are different flows for different architectures. I build mostly Single Page Apps (with Angular). As far as I've understood it I have basically two options to authenticate and then authorize:

- Implicit Flow
- Resource Owner Password (just calling the token endpoint)

Everywhere I look, it is stated that Implicit flow would be better (in one regard or the other).

Why is that?

I would be the product owner of both the API and the SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at several reasons for the Implicit flow being better than the Resource Owner Password:

1. The `/token` endpoint should require a client secret and single page applications (SPA) have no way of keeping their secrets safe.
2. Users usually have more trust in the OAuth2 server than applications using it. When using the Resource Owner Password flow, your application reads the username and password, so users may be reluctant to enter it.
3. Your application may have security issues that will expose the passwords to attackers - unnecessary risk.
4. With Resource Owner Password flow, it's hard to implement multiple different authentication methods. Using the Implicit flow, you get it for free.

Maybe someone else will add other reasons that didn't come to my mind.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I think points 2-4 would not be an issue for my current scenario. It would be a bespoke inhouse application. The users also certainly would not want to authenticate with google or facebook accounts for example.

A relevant point seems to be the "client secret" - Unfortunately I did not fully understand the concept it seems. Who would share the client secret? IDP and API? Or SPA and IDP? (because then it would aso be the SPA which needs to store it...)

IDP = Identity Server,
API = Resource Server,
SPA = Angular

Comment: To use an OAuth2 provider, you need to register your client first (the SPA application). You will get or provide a client_id and a client secret (password). These are used for authentication when accessing some OAuth2 provider resources, such as the `token` endpoint. But in SPAs, you would have to keep the secret in a browser, which means visible to all users of your SPA.

Comment: Point 1 is something that is worth mentioning, but with IdSvr client definitions you can also specifically state `RequireClientSecret=false` so you don't strictly need to maintain an (unsecure) client secret. As you say, SPA (or in fact *any* client that is installed on an enduser machine) secrets are hard/impossible to keep secret so why bother? Set `RequireClientSecret` to false and embrace the fact that authorisation is coming from your user's credentials, not your client.

Comment: Mashton, thanks for the info. I think the option is there mainly for the mobile apps using the Authentication Code Grant flow. But you could want it to be authenticated for some other application. And I don't know whether the `token` endpoint supports CORS headers necessary for SPAs.

Comment: Because `RequireClientSecret` is a `Client` setting you can obviously have different clients defined for different applications - some that use a flow where a client secret is impossible to keep secret, and others where it is needed. As for CORS, yes it is possible - that is just part of the `ConfigureServices` of your whole IdSvr app, not specific to using the identity server libraries. As usual, just define the origins you will accept calls from (i.e. the host of the SPA)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the good points Ján has made, it is worth noting that you won't get SSO if you use Resource Owner Password flow. If you use implicit flow the Identity Server can store the user like any website can, whereas with Resource Owner Password you cannot see if the user has previously authenticated for another service with the Identity Server.